# How do I find all the streams from a live IHeartRadio station?

Tags: node.js, icecast

I'm trying to find the entire stream list from a live IHeartRadio station (all streams available), and I've seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/857749/672063), but they've since changed it, and now window.__store is null. Is there another way to find streams? I've looked around, and the only stuff I can find on IHeart seems to be [this module](https://github.com/TooTallNate/iheart), which does not seem to work for me. I've been at this for a good 3-4 hours, and have given up and gone last resort to come here. Also, I've seen methods where people use mitmproxy to inspect the traffic, but I need the icecast stream, specifically, which I cannot find at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now actually published a module that fixes this exact issue. It uses the Public IHeartRadio API to search and get streams. It can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iheartradio).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, while window.__store is now being set to null, if you pause the website while it's loading using the developer console, you can search for `streams` and they will show up. You can also do this using Postman.